# Getting Eloquent field from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Products that have Models. I need to get some fields from all the Products and its Model slug. This is my code:

```
$query = Product::with('model');

$query->orderBy('order', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->skip($skip)->take($take);   

return $query->get(['id', 'name', 'front_image', 'back_image', 'slug']),
```

Its returning something like:

```
{
  "id": 39,
  "name": "ASD1",
  "front_image": "adasdsa.jpg",
  "back_image": "2evewa.jpg",
  "slug": "asd1",
  "model": null
}
```

How can I take model.slug?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to accomplish? Are you fetching the JSON via an Ajax request? If so, can you add the javascript that retrieves this data? Or do you want to have the slug in PHP?

Comment: Im testing this endpoint through postman and the json I pasted is the response

Comment: I need all my products and its model slug. If I do just Product::with('model')->get(); it works and gives me all the fields from product and its model but I dont want to make all data visible so i only want id, name, front_image, back_image and slug from product and the slug from the model @rofavadeka

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Perhaps it's best to manage this in the model; Do you use this other hidden data in the model any where else? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Answer (score 0):

The get method is used to tell eloquent to execute a query to the database.
To select only specific fields you can use the select method before get.

For example:

```
Product::with('model')->select('name', 'model.slug as model_slug')->get();
```